# Include JAR file in ant compilation

Tags: java, ant, jar

I want to compile some `.java` files into a JAR. I would like to use this JAR file in another application.

Is this a good way to use functions from my first application in my second application? My goal is to not duplicate code.

How can I edit the `build.xml` file for the second application to include the JAR file I created? When I compile my project, functions from JAR files are not resolved :

```
[javac] C:\HelloWorld\src\com\example\helloworld\HelloWorld.java:7: 
        package TOOLS does not exist  
[javac] import TOOLS.Logs;
```

---

EDIT:
When I add the `javac` task in my `build.xml`, compilation fails because other packages are not found:

```
[javac] Compiling 1 source file
[javac] C:\HelloWorld\src\com\example\hellowolrd\HelloWorld.java:3: 
        package android.app does not exist
[javac] import android.app.Activity;
[javac]                   ^
```

Why are my original packages not found after I include the JAR file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's good practice generally to subdivide functionality into libraries for reuse, ease-of-development etc. It'll speed development if they're separately built, and you can easily distribute functionality to successive projects.

You can reference your jar thus:

```
  <javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         classpath="xyz.jar"
         debug="on"
  />
```

See the [javac](http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/en/manual/CoreTasks/javac.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

But When I add javac task in my build.xml, now compilation failed because others packages are not found :

    [javac] Compiling 1 source file
    [javac] C:\HelloWorld\src\com\example\hellowolrd\HelloWorld.java:3: package android.app does not exist
    [javac] import android.app.Activity;
    [javac]                   ^

Why my original packages are not found anymore after including .jar file ?

Comment: It will be unrelated to adding that jar. Do you need to specify that jar alongside *other* jars ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your JAR to your classpath.

```
 <javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         classpath="xyz.jar"
         debug="on"
         source="1.4"
  />
```

See [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

But When I add javac task in my build.xml, now compilation failed because others packages are not found :

    [javac] Compiling 1 source file
    [javac] C:\HelloWorld\src\com\example\hellowolrd\HelloWorld.java:3: package android.app does not exist
    [javac] import android.app.Activity;
    [javac]                   ^

Why my original packages are not found anymore after including .jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the classpath or classpathref attribute in the javac task, or include a nested classpath element, as described in the [javac ant task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).

Note : packages in Java should be in lowercase.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

But When I add javac task in my build.xml, now compilation failed because others packages are not found :

    [javac] Compiling 1 source file
    [javac] C:\HelloWorld\src\com\example\hellowolrd\HelloWorld.java:3: package android.app does not exist
    [javac] import android.app.Activity;
    [javac]                   ^

Why my original packages are not found anymore after including .jar file ?